# spring boot : how to set db2 encryption password for column value encryption

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption, db2

I want to set db2 encryption password command when spring boot starts a connection with my db2. Basically some of the columns in my table are encrypted. I tried hibernate mapper @ColumnTransformer(read="decrypt_char(COLUMN_NAME,'password')",write="encrypt(?,'password')").

```
That does not work. After some look around I found that I have to set the encryption password with the following command when the database connection is established from spring boot application properties file.

     SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD ='password'(This is DB2 specific)

I dont see any way of setting this in spring boot. I believe there must be a property defined in application.properties which would set this. Currently I am just passing db2 connection as per following

spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=om.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

Any help is appreciated.
```

Comment: Is there a syntax for supplying the password in the JDBC connection string?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is on how to pass the encryption password special registry variable setting via jdbc url, then the answer is: you need to add to the url something like the following:

```
...;specialRegisters=ENCRYPTION PASSWORD='password';
```

[URL format for IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 4 connectivity](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052342.html)